# A silly question about $\mathbb{Z}_1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the cyclic group of one element, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_1$, just  $\mathbb{Z}$? I would think not, since the integers have more than one elements. Or is it just $\langle 1\rangle$, the abelian group generated by $1$, if I'm not mistaken, isn't this isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$? Finally, is it also true that $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Just wanted some clarification.

Comment: The cyclic group of one element is a group with only the identity element.  It is very different from the infinite group $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: To add, the set in $\mathbb Z_1$ contains only $0$. Good question though.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb Z_1=\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z\cong\langle 0\rangle$ which contains only zero as others have already mentioned.

Comment: Note also that $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\mathbb Z / \mathbb Z_1$ isn't well-defined unless you fix an embedding of $\mathbb Z_1$ into $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg There is only one such embedding, no?

Comment: Yes, but it is bad style to use these embeddings before explicitly defining them. If you regard elements of a quotient module as cosets, then the only element of $\mathbb Z_1$ is the coset $\mathbb Z$ of $\mathbb Z$, and it is weird to identify it with the element $0$ of $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When making quotients of two abelian groups  $B\subset A$ (or rings, or whatever), $A/B$ is the set of equivalence classes of the relation in $A$ defined by:
\begin{equation*}
xRy\iff x-y \in B
\end{equation*}
with some laws of addition or multiplication based on those of $A$.
In particular, if $A=B=\mathbb{Z}$, then there is only one equivalence class, and hence $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}_{1}$ is a trivial group. When things like that puzzle you it is best to go back to the definition of the considered objects.

Answer (score 1):

The cyclic group of order $1$ is indeed *not* $\mathbb{Z}$, because of the reason in your post.

The abelian group generated by one element with no relations is indeed $\mathbb{Z}$.

The quotient $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial, as is the case for any group $G$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$.